# <img src="{{media url="someurl"}}"> results in broken url & wont get parsed

Tags: magento-1.7, template

I'm having some problems within the product description as my client wants to use the wysiwyg-editor and its image upload features.
Sadly all inserted image variables won't get parsed correctly so the output is something like this:

```
<img src="{{media url="someurl"}}">
```

which is in fact the same as the raw input.

Any suggestions how to fix this? I obviously don't want to change all image links to something hardcoded even if my client has just around 100 products ;)

(Magento 1.7.0.2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

most themes like the one my client is using use this syntax to get the product description (containing wysiwyg codes):

```
echo $_product->getDescription();
```

but instead you have to use this not intuitive construction:

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description');
```

which then does the transforming.

(while normally not the solution: there is also an attribute for magento attributes that enables wysiwyg parsing and will be checked inside the *productAttribute*-function)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
<?php 
$_product=Mage::registry('current_product');
$myattribute=$_product->getData('judaica_size_guide');
$_cmsHelper = Mage::helper('cms');
$_process = $_cmsHelper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
echo $_process->filter($myattribute);
```

OR

```
<?php 
 $_product=Mage::registry('current_product');
 $myattribute=$_product->getData('judaica_size_guide');
echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(),$myattribute,'description');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try single quotes inside curly braces that would not break wysiwyg, I had same problem which get solved doing that way.

```
<img src="{{image url='someurl'}}">
```

Comment: sadly it doesn't help, same result

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no `image` directive. To include files from the media directory, use the `media` template tag (double quotes are fine):

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/img.ext"}}" />
```

If you see the markup *as is* in the frontend, this may be caused

- either by the WYSIWYG editor
- or by your theme,

converting HTML special characters to HTML entities, e.g. `<` becomes `&lt;`. You may check the description stored in the database. If characters are already converted there, it's likely an issue during collection of data. Otherwise check your frontend display.

Comment: oh typo with image, I meant media of course.
But still won't work and there is no html entity conversion, just the markup as it is pasted into the wysiwyg-editor (product page if it helps)
As far as I can tell the installation is pretty much genuine Magento with just custom theme on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin/Catalog and enable the option for

"Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories"

Change from "No" to "Yes" and then clear cache, {{media url=""}} now works ;)